# How to achieve synchronization of three threads using reentrant lock?

Tags: java, multithreading

Below specified code snippet prints numbers in sequence with synchronizing three threads using wait() and notify() methods. But the requirement is to achieve the same using reentrant locking mechanism.

```
class JoinTask {

    private int currentRank = 1;

    public void doJob(int rank, int printNo) {
        synchronized (this) {
            while (rank != currentRank) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("going to wait by thread:" + printNo);
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Job:" + printNo + " : " + currentRank);
            currentRank++;
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

public class ThreeThreadsPlay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JoinTask task = new JoinTask();

        Thread A = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                int k = 1;
                for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
                    task.doJob(k, 1);
                    k = k + 3;
                }}};

        Thread B = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                int k = 2;
                for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
                    task.doJob(k, 2);
                    k = k + 3;
                }}};

        Thread C = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                int k = 3;
                for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
                    task.doJob(k, 3);
                    k = k + 3;
                }}};
        C.start();
        B.start();
        A.start();
    }}
```

How can I achieve the same using reentrant locking?

Any other example using reentrant locking to provide such mechanism will also help. Furthermore, any information provided in this context will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Make an effort. `ReentrantLock` and `Condition` isn't much different from using `synchronized` and `wait/notify`.

Comment: I tried it.. but it was failing. Hence, I posted for some inputs. Instead of just giving some statement, some help would have been really appreciated.

Comment: The word is 'reentrant', not 'reenterant', and these locks are already reentrant. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proper implementation with `ReentrantLock/Conditional`. Note carefully the differences between this and what you attempted. The lock acquisition and release should really be handled in a `try-finally` block to avoid a lock being kept indefinitely, but you can find examples of that in other questions.

```
class JoinTask {

    private int currentRank = 1;
    final ReentrantLock l = new ReentrantLock();
    final Condition c = l.newCondition();

    public void doJob(int rank, int threadNumber) {
        l.lock();
        while(rank != currentRank) {
            c.await();
        }
        System.out.println("Job:" + threadNumber + " : " + currentRank);
        currentRank++;
        c.signalAll();
        l.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that this would work fine with the help of Condition class with ReentrantLock and will be appropriate as far as performance is considered as compared to ReentrantLock without Condition because in the latter case, more time is consumed as each thread will be keep on running to get its chance, however in the former case, It has used wait and notify functionality. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for understanding perfectly the answer!